# SQL statement not working - "Operand type clash: float is incompatible with date'

Tags: sql, stored-procedures

I'm a new to this field and i have a problem in executing this procedure it gives me this error: "Operand type clash: float is incompatible with date"

```
create proc store.checks_pro

(
@book_id int ,
@check_no int,
@check_date date ,
@check_status tinyint ,
@check_amount float,
@check_funder_name varchar (30),
@check_cash_type tinyint,
@check_cash_checkno varchar (20),
@check_notes varchar(100),
@check_userid int ,
@insertion_userid int ,
@insertiondate datetime 
)
as
begin
insert into  checks (book_id,check_amount,check_cash_checkno,check_cash_type,check_date,check_funder_name,check_no,check_notes,check_status,check_userid,insertion_userid,insertiondate)
values (@book_id,@check_no,@check_date,@check_status,@check_amount,@check_funder_name,@check_cash_type,@check_cash_checkno,@check_notes,@check_userid,@insertion_userid,@insertiondate)


end
```

Comment: Which DBMS are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the revised error, your problem is obvious.  The values are not matching your columns.  You are inserting `@check_date` in to the column `check_cash_checkno`.

Answer (score 3):

Check your `INSERT` statement. You are inserting `@check_date` into `check_cash_checkno` column.

Answer (score 1):

Just going by column and variable names, there seems to be a considerable mismatch in the order you're supplying the parameters:

```
insert into  checks (
book_id,check_amount,check_cash_checkno,check_cash_type,check_date,check_funder_name,
check_no,check_notes,check_status,check_userid,insertion_userid,insertiondate)
values (
@book_id,@check_no,@check_date,@check_status,@check_amount,@check_funder_name,
@check_cash_type,@check_cash_checkno,@check_notes,@check_userid,@insertion_userid,@insertiondate)
```

E.g. `@check_date` is aliging with the `check_cash_checkno` column, `@check_notes` aligns with `check_status`, etc.

I would guess that it should be re-written as:

```
insert into  checks (
book_id,check_amount,check_cash_checkno,check_cash_type,check_date,check_funder_name,
check_no,check_notes,check_status,check_userid,insertion_userid,insertiondate)
values (
@book_id,@check_amount,@check_cash_checkno,@check_cash_type,@check_date,@check_funder_name,
@check_no,@check_notes,@check_status,@check_userid,@insertion_userid,@insertiondate)
```

This is one of those unfortunate places where SQL fails to live up to the relational ideal that we should reference columns (attributes) by name and not by ordinal position - you have to supply the parameters or values in the `VALUES` clause in an order that matches the order you gave for the columns of the `INSERT` statement.

Answer (score 0):

Follow the order to insert value.

```
    insert into  checks
    (
    book_id,
    check_amount,
    check_cash_checkno,
    check_cash_type,
    check_date,
    check_funder_name,
    check_no,
    check_notes,
    check_status,
    check_userid,
    insertion_userid,
    insertiondate
    )
    values
    (
    @book_id,
    @check_amount,
    @check_cash_checkno,
    @check_cash_type,
    @check_date,
    @check_funder_name,
    @check_no,
    @check_notes,
    @check_status,
    @check_userid,
    @insertion_userid,
    @insertiondate
    )
```

Simple example to reproduce your error:

```
create table test
(
sdate date,
roll nvarchar(50)
)
insert into test(sdate,roll) values(1,'2008-2-2') --false

insert into test(sdate,roll) values('2008-2-2',1) --true
```

Answer (score 0):

```
INSERT INTO 
checks (book_id,check_amount,check_cash_checkno,check_cash_type,check_date,check_funder_name,check_no,check_notes,check_status,check_userid,insertion_userid,insertiondate)
VALUES    
(@book_id,@check_amount,@check_cash_checkno,@check_cash_type,@check_date,@check_funder_name,@check_no,@check_notes,@check_status,@check_userid,@insertion_userid,@insertiondate)
```

Many of the inserted values did not match the selected column order.